# Not able to print full string array

Tags: function, go

I'm trying to return a string array from a function, but it is printing only the last index position value. Here is my code and output.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    myquote := varFunc("Go", "Bunny", "Let's", "Change", "ourself")
    fmt.Println("here also:", myquote)

}

func varFunc(s ...string) string {

    fmt.Println(s)

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", s)
    quote := ""
    for _, v := range s {

        quote = v
        fmt.Println("init: ", quote)
    }
    fmt.Println("is there: ", quote)
    return quote

}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/jyZDL5oPmcz

My output:

```
[Go Bunny Let's Change ourself]
[]string
init:  Go
init:  Bunny
init:  Let's
init:  Change
init:  ourself
is there:  ourself
here also: ourself

Program exited.
```

Comment: If you want to return "string array from func" than you need to `return s` but you `return quote`

Answer (score 3):

Because you are overwriting the last value with `=` operator. If i understood correctly you are trying to print array as a single string. Apply `+=` symbol to `qoute` and it should work for you.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    myquote := varFunc("Go", "Bunny", "Let's", "Change", "ourself")
    fmt.Println("here also:", myquote)

}

func varFunc(s ...string) string {

    fmt.Println(s)

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", s)
    quote := ""
    for _, v := range s {

        quote += v + " "
        fmt.Println("init: ", quote)
    }
    fmt.Println("is there: ", quote)
    return quote

}
```

Comment: Note: "I'm trying to return a **string array** from a function"

Answer (score 2):

Your code returns last value of `quote` which is the value on last iteration on string array `s`.

If you need to return string array `s` - return it. Excuse me for truism.

```
func varFunc(s ...string) []string {

    fmt.Println(s)

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", s)
    quote := ""
    for _, v := range s {

        quote = v
        fmt.Println("init: ", quote)
    }
    fmt.Println("is there: ", quote)
    return s

}
```